# How to ignore git controlled file for pending changes locally

Tags: git, gitignore

On my project, the team is not supposed to ever checkin changes to schema.rb. Schema.rb is, however, controlled by git.

Basically, I just don't want to see schema.rb show up as a pending change ever.

Comment: You need a server hook, or a different way of versioning that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`

and then if at any point you want to undo that

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`

[Source here](http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/)

Comment: Brilliant! Good stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree) it seems you may want to use

```
git update-index --skip-worktree
```

Comment: I didn't try this one. The git update-index --assume-unchanged <file> worked great.